# How To Re-Order a Persistent Table Index Efficiently?

Tags: ios, algorithm, uitableview

I have a list in a UITableView, that I’m going to let the user reorder and have this order persisted in Core Data / CloudKit. If each item in the list has an index value stored in the database of type Int, I will have to immediately rewrite the index values for the entire list in the situation where someone moves a cell up to be the first item in the list (worst case scenario). I thought I could possibly avert this update to the entire database table’s contents by using a Double as the index value and simply setting the inserted item’s index value to halfway between the two indexes it’s been inserted between.

This seems like a solution until you keep moving items to the same position, for example, continually inserting items between the first and second item in the list. With a list of 3 items with index values 1, 2, 3, you only have to keep moving item 3 between item 1 and 2, 13 times to reach the limits of this algorithm with a Swift Double.

So to solve this, should I implement this solution, and then also implement a re-indexing operation that rewrites the database index values to Int precision as soon as the app activity is less busy and able to perform the more expensive operation quickly.

I really can’t think of any other way to solve this.

Comment: I wouldn't keep the position of the items with the items themselves.  Keep an array that maintains the order of the items and keep that array as a separate item in CoreData.

Comment: @vacawama what would the benefit of that be? As it is I’m not really storing the index on the item entity, I’m storing it on an associate entity that maintains some data about when the item was added to the list, because an item can be added to multiple lists.

Comment: Your initial description sounded like you had to update all of the items if their relative positions moved.  I was suggesting that you maintain the smallest representation of the ordering as an array of ids in CoreData and only that array would need updating upon reordering.